# How to use <Link> tag inside <option> tag in React

Tags: reactjs, react-router-dom

I'm using React with bootstrap and I want to add Links in my drop down options. I'm not getting any way how to use `<Link>` tag within `<option>` tag.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import {getOptions} from './dropdownOptions';
class Navbar extends Component {
    state = {
        options : getOptions()
    };
    render() {
        return (

            <nav className="navbar navbar-dark bg-dark navbar-expand-md pb-2">
                <h1 className="navbar-brand">Navbar Heading</h1> 
                <select className="nav-item">
                    {this.state.options.map(options =><option key={options.id}>{options.label}</option>)}
                </select>
            </nav>          
        );
    }
}

export default Navbar
```

I'm importing an array of dropdown items by function `getOptions()` and then using them inside `<select>` tag.

```
const options = [
    {
        label:"Apples",
        id:0,
        value:0
    },
    {
        label:"Mangoes",
        id:1,
        value:1        
    },
    {
        label:"Bananas",
        id:2,
        value:2        
    }
];

export function getOptions() {
    return options;
}
```

[image: Navbar]

I have 3 more components, named "Apples", "Mangoes" and "Bananas"
that I want to display below navbar when I select the desired dropdown
How can I link the options using `<Link>` tag

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use `<Links>` (or `<a>`) elements within a  element, that's invalid HTML. To use a dropdown in React with links, I would suggest using a library like Downshift (https://github.com/downshift-js/downshift), which provides you with the necessary primitives to build a dropdown yourself.

Comment: I searched for downshift but they only show how to build a dropdown menu, but I want to know how to link these option such that on clicking them, their respective component displays below navbar. Sorry if the question is common, I'm new to react